# Почему может быть Password authentication failed?

Tags: mysql, ssh

Пытаясь сегодня подключится по SSH к MySQL серверу внезапно получил ошибку

> Password authentication failed

Подумал что просто забыл пароль, залез на сервер через по ssh и руками подключился к MySQL от другого пользователя , дальше поменял пароль нужного юзера

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='abat';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Все поменялось успешно, перезагрузил mysql

```
 service mysql stop
 service mysql start
```

Пытаюсь соединиться с MySQL через клиент по ssh (клиент Navicat), и ловлю эту ошибку.

Что еще можно сделать?

Админы повесели ssh на другой порт 2002, но и я пытаюсь подключиться на 2002. 
Что еще можно попробовать? В чем может быть причина?

Напрямую все работает, не работает именно ssh доступ.

Comment: как обычно: смотрите логи.